# select a diagonal area in paint.net

Tags: selection, paint.net

In Paint.net, is it possible to select a quadrilateral area with diagonal faces? How?

Comment: You can't split pixels if that's what your asking, a diagonal line will cut through pixels, so it will give you a saw-tooth pattern

Comment: I'm not a Paint.NET user, but as food for thought I'll tell you what I'd do in Photoshop. I'd select a normal (parallel to axis) rectangle, switch to quickmask mode, rotate the quickmask layer 45deg, and switch back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a rectangular selection and then rotate the selection box.

1. Activate the `Select` tool, typically shortcut key `s`.
2. Draw an approximate (or random) sized square.
3. Activate the `Move Selection` tool, typically shortcut key `mm`.

   - This is a different tool than the `Move Selected Pixels`.
4. You should be now able move your mouse until you see ability to rotate your selection box (not the pixels). You can also move the selection box, adjust its size.

   - Tip: Holding `shift` key while rotating will jump to common rotation angles.

[image: paint.net 5.0.2 visual showcase of tools to rotate selection]

Comment: right and left MB both do selections... Needs more detailed explanation. -1

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new layer. Use Line tool to draw a closed area. Then use the Magic Wand tool to create the selection. Switch to your previous layer and you have your selection

Answer (score 1):

It's not something that's built in, but there might be a plugin that will do what you want (or a good approximation - see Ivo's comment).

The plugins can be found on the [Paint.NET forum plugins board](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewforum.php?f=16&sid=cb446c8198e481e947bdab9935438e69)